# Які українські замінники слову "капча" (captcha) може запропонувати шановне товариство?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, відповідник

Намагаюся перекласти слово "captcha". Поки що натрапив на "чилюд": https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kapcha

Але воно незрозуміле з першого погляду, і важко вимовляється. Хотілося б уникнути перекладу двома словами. Що скажете про "протибот" та "янероботка"?

Comment: Про всьак зазначу, шчо _CAPTCHA_ цье скороченье від _Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart_.

Comment: Тема запитання цікава, але саме запитання оформлене як **запрошення до субʼєктивних думок**, на противагу до тих, що ґрунтуються на фактах і поважних джерелах.

Comment: *чилюд* -- чудово, трошки незвично, але чудово!!

Comment: bytebuster, саме суб’єктивні думки мене і цікавлять, об’єктивних вистачає - це буде калька "капча", так само як "текст", "документ", "папір" та решта, і всі ці слова - неукраїнські. Я ж займаюся локалізацією, а не транслітерацією. До того ж, під час війни народжується мій нарід, і йому для росту потрібна мова.

Answer (score 3):

«Протибот» мені особисто дуже подобається.

Але можливість застосування цього слова залежить від контексту. У деяких (наприклад, офіційних) контекстах, можливо, доведеться обмежитися вже вживаними термінами. А якихось уживаних варіантів, окрім «CAPTCHA» й «капча», я не бачу:

- Microsoft ([Microsoft Terminology Collection і Translations in Localized Microsoft Products](//www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?searchTerm=captcha&langID=Ukrainian&Source=true&productid=All+Products)): «тест CAPTCHA», «Captcha», «Перевірка за допомогою CAPTCHA».
- Вікіпедії (з кириличною абеткою: [українська](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CAPTCHA&oldid=19110373), [російська](//ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0&oldid=97391326), [болгарська](//bg.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CAPTCHA&oldid=8899155): «CAPTCHA», «капча».
- Книги ([Кевін Неллі «Невідворотне»](//books.google.com/books?id=W3tiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT206&dq=captcha), [Артем Захарченко «Інтернет-медіа: інтерактивний навчальний посібник для курсу „Підтримка сайту“»](//books.google.com/books?id=UOfrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&dq=captcha)): «візуальна перевірка», «капча», «CAPTCHA».

Отож в контекстах, де не дозволено вигадувати своє, мабуть, доведеться зупинитися на «CAPTCHA» чи «капча». Але загалом «протибот», по-моєму, дуже інтуїтивно зрозумілий (його майже не можна не зрозуміти; в крайньому разі — «протиробот»). І в словниках є інші слова, утворені так само: протигаз, протиструм, протитиск, протиудар тощо.

Answer (score 1):

Мені здається, що варіант "чилюд" на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kapcha) є досить дотепним та включає в собі значення слова: "Перевіряє чи ви людина?".

Взагалі перекласти це слово буде складно, бо потрібно врахувати, що це все ж таки абревіатура від:

> «completely automated public turing test to tell computers and humans
>   apart»

Перекладається як:

> повністю автоматизований публічний тест Тюринга для розрізнення
>   комп'ютерів і людей ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA))

Можливо із цим слово краще поступити так само як із словом "НАТО". Тобто вживати "капча", а для пояснення використовувати вже описовий переклад.

Крім того, якщо ми говоримо про варіант "протибот" - слово "бот" - запозичення. Те ж саме із словом "яне**робот**ка". А навіщо замінювати одне запозичення на інше?

Comment: Слово *робот* Словьанського (тут [Чеського](https://www.ety.monline.com/word/robot)) роду, такого ж пньа ьак і *робота*.